# Where can I find the Stack's dev survey in SQLite form

Tags: support, survey, survey-2018

I was just reading the Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2018, and was wondering if I could find it as a table, preferably in SQLite readable form, so that I might be able to overlay the data with other things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"We’ll make the anonymized results of the survey available for download under the Open Database License (ODbL) on **May 30th**. In the meantime, you can see the full data sets from previous years [here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/)."*

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

As stated near the bottom of [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/13/2018-developer-survey-results-live/) announcing the 2018 survey results.

Comment: @Lucifer: Let's keep it in line with the blog post as much as possible ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Keep [reading](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/13/2018-developer-survey-results-live/?cb=1):

> We’ll make the anonymized results of the survey available for download under the Open Database License (ODbL) on May 30<sup>th</sup>. In the meantime, you can see the full data sets from previous years [here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/).

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that @Raphael, THANKS!